# React Native save image from CameraRoll.getPhotos() in Expo App

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using [CameraRoll.getPhotos](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html#getphotos) function to obtain images from photo album. I have no problem accessing the images, but I would like to edit one of the images, and save it back to Photo Album.

```
getPhotos = () => {
    CameraRoll.getPhotos({
        first: 20,
        assetType: 'Photos'
    })
    .then(r => this.setState({ photos: r.edges, isLoaded: true }));
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getPhotos();
}

render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
        <View style={styles.pageWrapper}>
            <View>
                {this.state.isLoaded && 
                <Image source={{uri: this.state.photos[this.state.index].node.image.uri}} style={{width: width, height: width}} />
                }
            </View>
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}>
                {
                    this.state.photos.map((p, i) => {
                        return (
                            <TouchableHighlight style={{opacity: i === this.state.index ? 0.5 : 1}} key={i} onPress={() => this.setIndex(i)}>
                                <Image style={{width: width / 4, height: width / 4}} source={{uri: p.node.image.uri}} />
                            </TouchableHighlight>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

I would like to pass the `uri` of the image, and save it to an image file. However, the `uri` is in `asset-library://` format, and it cannot be loaded in this way in next page:

```
<Image source={{uri: assetLibraryURI}} />
```

I pass the `assetLibraryURI` to next page by:

```
onPressHeaderRight() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    navigate('Editor', { assetLibraryURI: this.state.photos[this.state.index].node.image.uri });
}
```

What did I miss?

p.s. I'm working in Expo App, i.e. haven't ejected the App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this does not answer your question directly I think its relevant to your question.

`CameraRoll` API needs you to link `RCTCameraRoll` library in react-native-cli project. This might cause some problem when using it with expo.

> `CameraRoll` provides access to the local camera roll / gallery.
>   Before using this you must link the `RCTCameraRoll` library. You can
>   refer to [Linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html) for help.

Expo has a different API for integrating picture gallery. You can read about it more [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker.html).

> ### ImagePicker
>
> Provides access to the system’s UI for selecting images from the
>   phone’s photo library or taking a photo with the camera.

You can use [`Expo.ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync(options)`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker.html#expoimagepickerlaunchimagelibraryasyncoptions) for possible better performance. This method also has `base64` prop that can be easier to use if the `uri` result is same as before (`asset-library://` format).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I'm looking into `ImagePicker` as well. However, unlike `CameraRoll`, the `ImagePicker` cannot show the images with a custom layout. It can only launch an image picker to select an image. If I would like to use custom layout to show images and select image for further processing, I have to **eject** my App inevitably, in order to link up with the `RCTCameraRoll` library. Is that right?

Comment: I never actually tried using expo and `RCTCameraRoll` together. Being able to trigger image picking screen shows that it is somehow linked but the linked library can be different since expo uses its own fork of react-native. If you need doing something that expo, default react-native or something other than 3rd party expo packages do you need to eject. I'm sorry I know I couldn't be much help but at least I wanted to give you an option if you didn't already know.

Comment: In current stable version (v0.49), the Xcode project generated after eject is difficult to build, mainly due to the 4 libraries required by the project is unable to be downloaded automatically during build process.

Comment: If you are already planing to eject your project, not too into the project and don't have much dependency on expo libraries, you can consider creating a clean project with react-native-cli and then moving your javascript files into project. This way your project would be much more consistent and ready for future updates without doing much custom actions. This option might need you to rewrite some parts of your projects or might need you to add some 3rd party libraries to achieve same functionality.

Comment: Agreed, rewriting those Expo libraries also take time.